# trying to make my discord python bot write to a file

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to write a discord bot, that when you type !create, you can type in the scores of every person and it should save the scores to a text file to retrieve them later, but it is not writing anything to the text file and I don't know why this is happening.

My Code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
channel = client.get_channel("channelid")

file = open("TournamentScores.txt", "a")

tournament = False
scoreset1 = False
scoreset2 = False


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("~Bot Started~")
    channel = client.get_channel("channelid")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("received message") 
    channel = client.get_channel("channelid")
    
    global tournament, scoreset1, scoreset2

    if message.content.startswith("!create") and not tournament:
        print("Tournament Created")
        tournament = True
        await message.channel.send("Goals for Conner:")
        file.write("~Tournament~ \n")

    
    elif message.content.isdigit():
        if tournament and not scoreset1:
            scoreset1 = True
            ConnerTemplate = "Conner - " + message.content
            file.writelines(ConnerTemplate + " \n")
            await message.channel.send("Goals for Ewan:")

        elif scoreset1 and not scoreset2:
            scoreset2 = True
            EwanTemplate = "Ewan - " + message.content
            file.writelines(EwanTemplate + " \n")
            await message.channel.send("Goals for Jack:")
        
        elif scoreset2 == True and tournament == True:
            JackTemplate = "Jack - " + message.content
            file.writelines(JackTemplate + " \n")
            await message.channel.send("Goals for Thomas:")

            tournament = False
            
        elif not tournament and file == open:
            ThomasTemplate = "Thomas - " + message.content
            file.writelines(ThomasTemplate + " \n")          

            file.close()

            tournament = False
```

Comment: Maybe none of the conditions of the `if` statements in which the file is written are true?

Comment: Or maybe the file is never closed and not yet flushed when you look at it? e.g. `file` will never be equal to the `open` function so the last `elif` will never be executed.

Comment: Try using a debugger to step through the function.

Answer (score 0):

One of the following must be going wrong:

The code might never be entering this if statement. Maybe `tournament` is True, or the message does not actually start with `!create`?

```
if message.content.startswith("!create") and not tournament:
```

If the code is actually entering the if statement (you can confirm by printing something in the if), then it might be that this await never completes:

```
await message.channel.send("Goals for Conner:")
```

If you're getting past that line, then this line is not writing to the file for some reason:

```
file.write("~Tournament~ \n")
```

If you can print Tournament here and see it, then the file write is failing for some reason.

You can try opening and closing the file when you go to write to it instead, like this:

```
with open("TournamentScores.txt", "a") as infile:
     infile.write("~Tournament~ \n")
```